# Zoom out D3 Force-Directed Graph without using mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming

I've implemented zoom on [force-directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

```
svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", rescale))


function rescale() {
        var trans = d3.event.translate;
        var scale = d3.event.scale;

        svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + trans + ")"
                + " scale(" + scale + ")");
    }
```

Graph can be **zoomed in** either using mouse wheel or double click on it. I need some advice how to implement **zooming out** without using mouse wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift-double click should zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a trackpad-equipped Mac, the zooming gestures are actually the Mac scrolling gestures: Scrolling up with two fingers zooms in, scrolling down with two fingers zooms out - Assuming that the Scroll direction in the Preferences is set to *unnatural*.